Python layer in lambda via cdk
TL;DR: the requirements.txt file ends up the layer, not the actual modules.
I have a very simple Lambda, created by the cdk.
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda_python_alpha as aws_lambda_python
from aws_cdk import aws_iam, aws_lambda, Duration, Stack
from constructs import Construct


class Lambda(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str):
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id)

        aws_lambda_python.PythonFunction(
            self,
            "LambdaFunction",
            entry="src/lambda",
            index="size.py",
            handler="lambda_handler",
            runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            layers=[
                aws_lambda_python.PythonLayerVersion(
                    self,
                    "lambda-layer",
                    entry="src/layers/",
                    compatible_runtimes=[aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
                )
            ],
        )

This works, as in I see the lambda in the console, as well as the content of src/lambda, and a layer.
The file src/layers/requirements.txt exist, and is very small:
boto3
botocore
jsons
structlog

When I look at the layer: aws lambda get-layer-version-by-arn --arn <arn copied from the lambda console> and download/unzip Content.Location, I only get requirements.txt, not the actual modules. And of course, when running the lambda I get module jsons not found (for instance).
What do I need to do to get the actual dependecies, not the requirement file?

Can you add the output of cdk synth -vvv? It will be very verbose - try including the parts relevant to bulding the layer.
It might be worth defining a separate stack with just the layer (no lambda) in it, and synthing just that stack

That's interesting. I usually do not issue cdk synth, only cdk bootstrap --output cdk.out (where -vvv did not help) followed by cdk deploy --app cdk.out. With app.synth() in app.py, this works. Or so I thought up to today. Issuing first a cdk synth just now works, and I see the proper environment in the lambda layer. I am very very confused, and I think I will need to read more documentation. Thanks!

cdk deploy does a cdk synth first, so it should not have made a difference. There's no need to specify --output or --app, though - maybe that's the issue. -vvv is not going to "help", that's just to get more verbose logging. And you don't need to run cdk bootstrap more than once.

cdk bootstrap updates the bootstrapping things (bucket? Cloudformation stack? not too sure what in total) when a new version is released, so it needs to be run regularly-ish anyway. As it does a synth at the same time, it is useful to run it instead of synth. That's why bootstrap --out and deploy --app become useful, to have bootstrap store the newly synthesised template, and deploy use it, to have only one synth (which can be time consuming).

That's probably the cause of your issues - cdk bootstrap does not build your lambdas, and you're overriding the synth when specifying --app. The bootstrap template is updated every couple of months, so no need to re-run the deployment every time.
